# C++: Drawbacks to writing whole classes in Header files for small projects?

Tags: c++, header, coding-style

Just a style question...

I'm a lowly indie game dev working by myself, and I developed what I have been told is a 'bad' habit of writing whole classes in my headers.  Some of the benefits I know .h/.cpp file combos have are they allow code to be split into compilation chunks that won't need recompiled so long as they remain unchanged.  And allows for splitting interface from implementation.

However, neither of those things are of any benefit to me, since I tend to favour having my implementation in a spot where I can easily improve it, change it, read it.  And my compile times are nigh instantaneous (2-4 seconds, 15 if I updated SFML or Box2D to their latest versions and they need recompiled too)

Coding like this has been saving me a very noticeable amount of time I think, and since there are less files, my code feels less 'overwhelming' to me.

But in light of that, and in general, is there any compelling reason to follow the "file.cpp" for every "file.h" setup for a small project where compile time and interface/implementation separation are not priorities?

Comment: What do you put in your `.cpp` files, out of curiosity?

Comment: ... doh.  I just noticed a related question almost exactly like this one.  I wonder if it's considered good etiquette to delete repetitive questions?  Or bad.  I hate to think an answer someone is writing might get deleted too, haha

Comment: @Clairvoire:  Post a link to it and we can close this one as a duplicate.

Comment: @Greg: Usually it's class methods in the form of `void ClassName::methodName(parameter * list){ dostuff(); };`  I tend to do the same in the header file for non-inlined functions, but going between two files to do it is a pain sometimes.

Comment: @James: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810440/c-whole-class-in-h-file  It's a LOT more concise than my question, that's for sure, haha

Comment: That's not really a duplicate question:  your question is far more specific.  I think your question is fine as-is.

Comment: @Clairvoire: Thanks for looking for looking for and potential duplicates.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> is there any compelling reason to follow the "file.cpp" for every "file.h" setup for a small project where compile time and interface/implementation separation are not priorities?

Nope; there's nothing wrong with defining classes and functions in header files, especially not in small projects where compile times aren't a concern.

For what it's worth, my current, in-progress hobby project has 33 header files and a single .cpp file (not including unit tests).  That is largely due to just about everything being a template, though.

If you have a huge software project or if you need to encapsulate your code into a library and actually need the modularity, then it might make sense to split code out of a header file.  If you want to hide some implementation detail (e.g., if you have some ugly header that you don't want to include elsewhere in your project--WinAPI headers, for example), then it makes sense to split code into a separate source file to hide those details. Otherwise, it may just be a lot of work for not a lot of gain.

Comment: Okay, thank you!  Aha, I was wondering if it was really that simple.  Almost every style guide I read made a point of doing every header and .cpp file in that format.

Comment: edit: And yes, that is worth quite a bit!  It's good to know I'm not breaking some fundamental rule of C++ at the very least, if other folks do it in their own personal works too

Comment: The style guides say that because it's the rule.  The case described here is an exception.  Always teach the rule first because at some point the taught stop listening. That said, what you want to avoid is the pattern a former coworker used, which only used headers for the real code and then had one .cpp stitch the whole thing up. Took forever to build (80-100 files), it didn't link with our parts of the system (huge numbers of multiple-definition errors during link), it made `make -j` useless, and every build was a full build.

Comment: @Mike: Also, the days are gone when you had to `#include` everything together to maximize optimization opportunities.  The latest versions of all the major compilers now support whole program optimization, which does inlining and custom calling conventions between compilation units.  Of course, the price you pay for flipping that option is link times approaching the *compile-everything-together* build times.

Comment: @Mike: The convention exists for a reason, I won't forget that much.  For a large project, or one with other people working on it, I'd do quite a few things different, not just how my headers and files are set up, haha.  Kind of like how I cook for my family, and how I cook (microwave) for myself.

Answer (score 2):

I think both compile time and interface/implementation separation are good reasons.  Even if the former is not a problem right now, in most decent-sized projects, it does become a problem.

But, since you asked for other reasons, I think a big one is that it reduces dependencies.  The implementation of your class probably requires more `#includes` than the interface.  But if you put the implementation in the header file, you drag along those dependencies with the header.  Then every other file that includes that also has those dependencies.

There is no one-size-fits-all rule, though.  And some classes (especially "small" ones) are probably best placed entirely in a header.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind!  For especially large classes with large methods, like physics solvers, etc, I'll make a .cpp file for them, though those classes are few and far between.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing sounds sensible for your situation.  Two other potential issues:

- one definition rule
- testing

If you've got just one cpp file and a couple dozen headers, then you can afford to be careless about the one definition rule (assuming you have include guards).  This could bite you if you one day find a need to move to compiling/linking the project as a number of translation units.  That might happen in not-so-obvious ways, such as wanting to let other people supply a library that they're to build using a couple of your headers.  implicitly (defined inside the class) or explicitly (using the keyword) `inline` functions will be ok, but beware others.  Usual rules for variables etc..

For testing: sometimes it helps to have at least a token .cpp file that includes the .h and gets compiles, just so you get some early warning if the contents of one header can't "stand alone", probably due to a forgetten #include.  If you have per-header test .cpp files then that kills two birds etc..  If you don't want testing at that level and are happy to clean up any minor dependency bugs reactively then might as well forget it.